# Does filtering classes for cpu profiling work in Java VisualVM?

Tags: java, profiling, profiler, visualvm, jvisualvm

I want to filter what classes are being cpu-profiled  in Java VisualVm (Version 1.7.0 b110325). For this, I tried under Profiler -> Settings -> CPU-Settings to set "**Profile only classes**" to my package under test, which had no effect. Then I tried to get rid of all java.* and sun.* classes by setting them in "**Do not profile classes**", which had no effect either.

Is this simply a bug? Or am I missing something? Is there a workaround? I mean other than:

- paying for a better profiler
- doing sampling by hand (see [One could use a profiler, but why not just halt the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160))
- switch to the Call Tree view, which is no good since only the Profiler view gives me the percentages of consumed CPU per method.

I want to do this mainly to get halfway correct percentages of consumed CPU per method. For this, I need to get rid of the  annoying measurements, e.g. for `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run()` (around 70%). Many users seem to have this problem, see e.g.

- [Java VisualVM giving bizarre results for CPU profiling - Has anyone else run into this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385991/java-visualvm-giving-bizarre-results-for-cpu-profiling-has-anyone-else-run-into)
- [rmi.transport.tcp.tcptransport Connectionhandler consumes much CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233078/rmi-transport-tcp-tcptransport-connectionhandler-consumes-much-cpu)
- [Can't see my own application methods in Java VisualVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243100/cant-see-my-own-application-methods-in-java-visualvm).

Comment: Is it your purpose to make the code run as fast as possible? or just to get some percentages, regardless of what they mean? "Time" as it's commonly used, is highly ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, my major goal is making the code run faster. I also would like to have an estimate on how much of the code should change. So I want to get a rough overview of all the hot spots and their severity. I think VisualVm's results would be acceptable for this in spite of using wall time - if only those few sun.* and java.* classes wouldn't mess up all the statistics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you see `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run()` in the profile is that you left the option **Profile new Runnables** selected.

Also, if you took a snapshot of your profiling session you would be able to see the whole callstack for any hotspot method - this way you could navigate from the `run()` method down to your own application logic methods, filtering out the noise generated by the **Profile new Runnables** option.

Comment: Thanks JB (+5), I will check that option on Monday - sounds like the solution :) I did take a snapshot, which gave me the Call Tree view, which is no good since only the Profiler view gives me the percentages of consumed CPU per method. Because of recursion, my callstack is too complex to get sensible performance information from it.

Comment: Thanks JB, disabling the option "Profile new Runnables" did the trick.

Comment: Please, be aware of the consequences of disabling the aforementioned option. With the option turned on you will get info about all the newly started threads/runnables automatically. With that option turned off you must be sure to provide exhaustive list of root methods.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since your goal is to make the code run as fast as possible, let me suggest how to do it.
I'm no expert on VisualVM, but I can tell you what works. (Only a few profilers actually tell you what you need to know, which is - *which lines of your code are on the stack a healthy fraction of wall-clock time*.)

The only measuring I ever bother with is some stopwatch on the overall time, or alternatively, if the code has something like a framerate, the number of frames per second. I don't need any sort of further precision breakdown, because it's at best a remote clue to what's wasting time (and more often totally irrelevant), when there's a very direct way to locate it.

If you don't want to do [random-pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), that's up to you, but it's proven to work, and [here's an example of a 43x speedup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773).

Basically, the idea is you get a (small, like 10) number of stack samples, taken at random wall-clock times.
Each sample consists (obviously) of a list of call sites, and possibly a non-call site at the end.
(If the sample is during I/O or sleep, it will end in the system call, which is just fine. That's what you want to know.)

If there is a way to speed up your code (and there almost certainly is), you will see it as a line of code that appears on at least one of the stack samples.
The probability it will appear on any one sample is exactly the same as the fraction of time it uses.
*So if there's a call site or other line of code using a healthy fraction of time, and you can avoid executing it, the overall time will decrease by that fraction.*

I don't know every profiler, but one I know that can tell you that is [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/).
Others may be able to do it.
They may be more spiffy, but they don't work any quicker or better than the manual method when your purpose is to maximize performance.

Comment: Please, be aware, that in JVM it might happen that a method won't ever appear on the stack trace even if executed quite frequently. The reason for this is the way the JVM allows for taking stack traces - a stack trace of a thread can be taken only on checkpoint which might not be inserted by JIT into every single method.

Comment: You're quite the "random pausing evangelist", Mike :) Thanks anyways for the reply, I would have upvoted it if I hadn't given a link to you describing that technique already. I did try it, but because of recursion, the callstack is quite complex. A profile view breaks it down into methods with a percentage of runtime, so the hot spots are much easier to see. Secondly, the profile view shows all the hot spots and their severity. This gives a good overview of what and how much tuning has to be done. Do you agree?

Comment: @DaveBall: It's not about hotspots and measuring. Yes the call stack is complex, and there is recursion. Even so, see if you can select it all and copy it out to an editor. Then study it and see if you can answer the simple question "What is it in the process of doing at that time and why is it doing it?" Then do it again just a few times. That will show you why it's spending the time, and it will show you what you should concentrate on. Don't be cowed by recursion or a complex stack. Any line of code you see on 2 samples out of 3 is costing you (2+1)/(3+2)=60% on average. Good hunting.

Comment: @DaveBall: The deeper the stack is, the better the hunting. Since you mention recursion, I would hazard a bet that is the reason for the time being spent. In my experience, notifications gone wild are one major cause of performance problems. (BTW: hotspots (where PC concentrates) almost never matter in real code like yours. Also if you see a high-inclusive-percent function, you're going to look inside it - wrong! Look for why it's being called. Profilers don't tell you that. Stack samples do.)

Comment: @DaveBall: Sorry to keep going. (I hate "evangelists".) You took 1 sample and saw a lot of recursion. The [Rule of Succession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) says, on average, when that happens, that recursion is costing you (1+1)/(1+2)=67%. So the chances are excellent you have already found the problem.

Comment: @Mike: No need to say "sorry", thanks for putting in the effort. But the recursion itself, a DFS, is not the problem, rather what is executed by a visitor at each item of the traversal. Hence the only information relevant in the callstack is the part within the innermost recursion call. Since the visitor is performing tasks in various situations (visitNode, visitEdge, backtrackNode, backtrackEdge, recursionTermination), I'd have to do a lot of sampling to get the big picture of hot spots. Since I prefer automation over repetitive manual work, I prefer a profiler.

Comment: @DaveBall: That's fine. I'm just pointing out that when you figure out what you can fix that will save significant time, you will see that it was in front of you on >1 of the first few stack samples.